# Setting jQuery UI datepicker to first date defined as valid

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am a novice using jQuery UI datepicker on a commerce site to set a shipping date.  I want to populate the date input field with the first *valid* shipping date, which is defined as:

- later than today; and
- either a Monday or a Tuesday

(There are other conditions, but I am ignoring them for the moment.)

As I write this, and for the next few days, the correct value of this date is 8/8/2011.

Here is the page:

http://www.lolacookies.com/gifts/

Here is my code, which is not working. The commented part is what's supposed to be doing the work.  The value of the input is not being set at all; in previous attempts the date has been set to the value of minDate, but not to any other value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: "+1d",
    maxDate: "+3M",
    showAnim: "blind",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/images/misc/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select a date"
});


//set firstShippingDate to value of minDate
//we don't ship on same day, so minDate is today + 1d
var firstShippingDate = $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );

//we ship only on Monday and Tuesday, so test for that
var dayOfWeek = firstShippingDate.getDay();

//if it's not Monday or Tuesday, advance firstShippingDate by one day and test again
while ( dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6 )
  {
    firstShippingDate.setTime(firstShippingDate.getTime() + 86400000);
    dayOfWeek = firstShippingDate.getDay();
  };

//should exit loop with firstShippingDate set to first Monday or Tuesday that's not today
//set datepicker to that firstShippingDate
$(".datepicker").datepicker( "setDate" , firstShippingDate );


function nonWorkingDates(date){
    var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
    var closedDates = [[06, 27, 2011], [06, 28, 2011], [06, 29, 2011], [07, 04, 2011]];
    var closedDays = [[Sunday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday]];
    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
        if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
            return [false];
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
        date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
        date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    return [true];
}


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to checkout the [DateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) library. It let's you do cool stuff like this to get the next monday:

```
Date.today().next().monday();
```

So in your case, you can do something like this to get the next monday or tuesday:

```
if (Date.today().is().monday()) {
  firstShippingDate = Date.today().next().tuesday();
} else {
  firstShippingDate = Date.today().next().monday();
}
```

Comment: Nifty -- I can think of a zillion uses.  Thanks!